# Does AdS$_3$ geometry have an angular momentum?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, angular-momentum, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Consider the following hierarchy of masses for three-dimensional Einstein geometries with a locally AdS$_3$ metric:

$$\text{global AdS}_3: M = -1/8G$$
$$\text{conical-defect-AdS}_3: -1/8G < M < 0$$
$$\text{Poincare-AdS}_3: M = 0$$
$$\text{massive BTZ}: M > 0$$

I know that massive BTZ black holes have an angular momentum. What happens to the angular momentum as you reduce the mass until the mass becomes negative and you get to global AdS$_3$?